# What does "no-ops" mean in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at [Mozilla scope cheat sheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet) and it states:

var

- function-scoped
- hoist to the top of its function
- redeclarations of the same name in the same scope are **no-ops**

I can't find any reference to the definition of "no-ops"? What does it mean? Does it mean "no operation", meaning it doesn't redeclare it, simply changes the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A no op (or no-op), 'for no operation', is a computer instruction that takes up a small amount of space but specifies no operation.  The computer processor simply moves to the next sequential instruction.

> redeclarations of the same name in the same scope are no-ops

If there is a re-declaration, then the instruction will *simply be skipped*.. i.e. it wont be redeclared.

[image]

**Red : Step skipped.**

Comment: Niet, who made you king? Off topic? A question about something that had no clear reference in the materials? I know what you can do

Comment: @MarkRobson If you found it helpful, mark it and end the topic here, move on . Defining off-topic in comments may not be what u want. :) Keep it simple :)

Comment: Yes, a description of what the JS compiler is doing would be good. In that an assignment it first creates a space on disc, then assigns a variable. therefore a no-ops would simply use the same space on disc and do the assignment.

Comment: Added your input to the answer as well. @MarkRobson

Comment: @thecbuilder this is great, instead of a glib understanding of it it makes total sense now. Apologies for idiots and their down votes!

Comment: this confuses things somewhat IMHO because in JS there isn't even really a concept of "redeclaration".  All declarations are hoisted, and multiple declarations for the same variable are simply ignored.  It's _initialisations_ that matter, albeit often declaration and initialisation can occur within the same statement.

Comment: @Alnitak That's exactly what's mentioned in the diagram : Red - Step skipped/ignored. Whats the confusion?

Comment: the confusion is because people conflate declaration and initialisation.

Comment: @Alnitak Point noted :)